# PyQt and gpiozero callbacks

Tags: python, pyqt, raspberry-pi

I have a PyQt application that should react when some hardware buttons are pressed on a Raspberry Pi.

Following the recipes [here](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#button), I can invoke a callback when the button is pressed.

```py
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause

def say_hello():
    print("Hello!")

button = Button(2)
button.when_pressed = say_hello
pause()
```

What is the best way to integrate this into PyQt's event loop?

I can only think of spinning a separate thread that listens to the button using the code above or just polling and then calls `Core.QTimer.singleShot()` to add a new event in the event queue. Is there a more natural / less heavyweight way of doing this?

Comment: Okay, 1) I find it strange that it does not run 2) If the callback is executed on another thread then to send the information you must use the Qt signals.

Comment: I like that. Would it be easy to expand it into an example?